# Julia FixedEffectsModels IV regression doesn't match R IV regression

Tags: r, julia

When I run (what I think is the same regression) in R and in Julia I get very different results. I think this is because the IV regression is using an indicator variable to instrument for another indicator variable but I can't figure out if I am doing something else wrong.

I have tried several different methods, but the data starts like this:

```
   rc D tau     May_ret     Jun_ret      Jul_ret     Aug_ret      Sep_ret
1 -43 0   0  0.04529617  0.02106667  0.009868421 0.032573290  0.010473186
2 -19 0   0  0.01973333  0.05752213 -0.020920502 0.027521368 -0.029535865
3  74 1   1  0.33505189  0.04494382 -0.150537640 0.246835440  0.010152284
4  54 1   1  0.03602649  0.06168831  0.030581040 0.002611276 -0.027027028
5  22 1   1 -0.01584158 -0.08417509 -0.088235296 0.012903226  0.100000001
6   7 1   1  0.02484472  0.08000000  0.039548021 0.065217391  0.006122449
```

D and tau are not perfectly linear, but they are close (and tau is being used to instrument for D).

My R code is

```
library(AER)
library(stargazer)

temp_df <- read.csv(file="output.csv")

addmay <- ivreg(May_ret ~ D*rc|tau*rc, data=temp_df)
addjun <- ivreg(Jun_ret ~ D*rc|tau*rc, data=temp_df)
addjul <- ivreg(Jul_ret ~ D*rc|tau*rc, data=temp_df)
addaug <- ivreg(Aug_ret ~ D*rc|tau*rc, data=temp_df)
addsep <- ivreg(Sep_ret ~ D*rc|tau*rc, data=temp_df)

stargazer(addmay, addjun, addjul, addaug, addsep, title="Addition Return Effect", align=TRUE, type="text", report="vc*t")
```

Which produces

```
========================================================================================================
                                                    Dependent variable:                                 
                    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        May_ret          Jun_ret          Jul_ret          Aug_ret          Sep_ret     
                          (1)              (2)              (3)              (4)              (5)       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
D                        0.006            0.033            -0.008           0.028           -0.044*     
                       t = 0.304        t = 1.600        t = -0.353       t = 1.283        t = -1.943   

rc                      -0.0001          -0.0001          -0.0003          -0.0003*          0.0002     
                       t = -0.736       t = -0.730       t = -1.495       t = -1.784       t = 1.094    

D:rc                     0.0002          -0.0002          0.001***          0.0002           0.0001     
                       t = 0.817        t = -0.747       t = 2.660        t = 0.706        t = 0.392    

Constant                 0.0002          -0.021*          -0.024*          -0.021*           0.009      
                       t = 0.014        t = -1.778       t = -1.831       t = -1.673       t = 0.654    

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations              827              828              824              823              818       
R2                       0.003            0.007            0.007            0.026            0.012      
Adjusted R2             -0.0005           0.004            0.004            0.023            0.009      
Residual Std. Error 0.106 (df = 823) 0.111 (df = 824) 0.125 (df = 820) 0.116 (df = 819) 0.123 (df = 814)
========================================================================================================
Note:                                                                        *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

And my Julia code is

```
using FixedEffectModels, CSV, RegressionTables;

test_df = CSV.read("output.csv");

additions = Dict("May" => reg(test_df, @model(May_ret ~ (D*rc~tau*rc))),
    "Jun" => reg(test_df, @model(Jun_ret ~ (D*rc~tau*rc))),
    "Jul" => reg(test_df, @model(Jul_ret ~ (D*rc~tau*rc))),
    "Aug" => reg(test_df, @model(Aug_ret ~ (D*rc~tau*rc))),
    "Sep" => reg(test_df, @model(Sep_ret ~ (D*rc~tau*rc))));
regtable(additions["May"], additions["Jun"], additions["Jul"], additions["Aug"], additions["Sep"]; below_statistic=:tstat, regression_statistics=[:nobs, :r2, :f])
```

Which produces

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
               May_ret    Jun_ret    Jul_ret    Aug_ret    Sep_ret
              --------   --------   --------   --------   --------
                   (1)        (2)        (3)        (4)        (5)
------------------------------------------------------------------
(Intercept)      0.008   -0.013**     -0.006     -0.021     -0.004
               (1.580)   (-2.603)   (-1.117)   (-1.673)   (-0.771)
D               -0.004      0.023     -0.032      0.028     -0.027
              (-0.268)    (1.503)   (-1.854)    (1.283)   (-1.627)
rc            0.000***   0.000***   0.000***     -0.000   0.000***
                 (NaN)      (NaN)      (NaN)   (-1.784)      (NaN)
D & rc           0.000     -0.000     0.001*      0.000      0.000
               (0.496)   (-1.372)    (2.198)    (0.706)    (1.189)
------------------------------------------------------------------
Estimator           IV         IV         IV         IV         IV
------------------------------------------------------------------
N                  827        828        824        823        818
R2               0.000      0.008      0.004      0.026      0.004
F                0.200      6.306      9.604      8.526      7.380
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As can be seen, the main difference is FixedEffectsModels seems to be dropping the rc variable from the regression. I have checked for multicollinearity but it does not seem like it is the problem. Is there a part of my code that I am using wrong?

I am trying to replicate Table 4 of Yen-Cheng Chang, Harrison Hong, Inessa Liskovich, Regression Discontinuity and the Price Effects of Stock Market Indexing, The Review of Financial Studies, Volume 28, Issue 1, January 2015, Pages 212–246, https://doi.org/10.1093/rfs/hhu041

And they provide part of the data. I uploaded the full data here: https://github.com/junder873/data.git

Comment: Added the libraries

Comment: Have you compared with `felm` in R?

Comment: I have tried to use `felm`, I can't quite figure out the correct format though since the IV I am using is being interacted with a non-IV

Comment: I wonder if data types are the issue. R may treat *D* and *tau* as factors and Julia treats them as integers. Also R may not be running an IV FE model but IV OLS or IV GLM model.

Comment: The data types could be true, but I wouldn't be sure why the Aug_ret value for both is the same (Julia rounded to 3 decimal places, R left on the fourth). That one should also be different if they are using fundamentally different models right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some work, I figured out my own answer. Julia FixedEffectModels was including the rc variable in both the endogenous and exogenous part of the regression. The correct way to fix this is to basically interact the variables beforehand. This will create the correct output. For example:

```
reg(test_df, @model(May_ret ~ rc + (rc_D + D~rc_tau+ tau)))
```

Where `rc_D` is `rc.*D` and `rc_tau` is `rc.*tau`, basically creating two new columns and adding them manually to the regression instead of letting the model decide which columns to add. This produces the same results.