# R: felm function with an interacted IV

Tags: r

I want to interact an IV variable with a non-IV variable and be able to add fixed effects with the felm function (the library is lfe).

I have 3 variables in my function, D (indicator variable), tau (indicator variable), and rc (continuous variable). D is endogenous and tau is exogenous, in the final equation it should be:

[image]

Where D is instrumented by tau. Doing this in the AER package with ivreg is easy, `ivreg(f0 ~ D*rc | tau*rc, data=df)`, but in felm I can't figure it out.

My current best guess is

```r
felm(f0 ~ 1 | 0 | (D*rc ~ tau*rc), data=df)
```

Which at least doesn't give an error, but the coefficients are completely different.

Comment: FYI, I had the same issue. It seems this is still an unresolved issue. See [https://github.com/sgaure/lfe/issues/5](https://github.com/sgaure/lfe/issues/5)

Comment: It doesn't look like it. The solution I used (in Julia, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55755226/) is similar to the comment on your link by @grantmcdermott. Basically, add a column to the dataframe of the interacted value, then instrument for the interacted variable and the endogenous variable, while putting the exogenous variable in the left part. So, in my case, I would do: `felm(f0 ~ rc | 0 | (rc_D + D ~ rc_tau + tau), data=df)`

Comment: I need to repeat this with thousands of interaction values...any idea on a way to scale your solution?